# get defined constants from current file only

Tags: php, constants

I have some constants defined in a file like:

```
define("staff", 20);
define("manager", 30);
define("director", 40);
```

they are not inside a class so

```
$class = new ReflectionClass("Foo");
$constants = $class->getConstants();
```

will not help.

Unfortunately the names are not prefixed like `PERMISSION_`

So the best option for me is to `get_defined_constants();` from the current file only

is this possible?

Comment: My approach would be to store the get_defined_constants(); before defining the new constants, and then compare the new list of get_defined_constants(); with the one previously stored.

Comment: @Ionut, indeed. I would go for a function used for adding constants (etc. calling `define()`) and keeping the constants names in say a global, keyed by `basename(__FILE__)` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done through get_defined_constant() method. Following will be the code to get those values.

```
include("/path_to_file/constant_file.php");

$constant_set = get_defined_constants(true);

echo $constant_set['user']['staff'];
echo $constant_set['user']['manager'];
echo $constant_set['user']['director'];
```

The working script with url: http://sugunan.net/demo/const.php

Comment: ahh, if only I had taken the time to read the docs on the `$categorized` parameter :) Thanks. You should include the full code in the post btw

Comment: But it shows all user defined constants, not from the current file only.

Comment: @Karolis if we use `get_defined_constants(true);` then it will return a multidimensional array, where the top level is the file names in which the constants were defined

Comment: @andrew no. These are NOT the file names in which the constants are declared. These are the names of PHP libraries. They have nothing in common.

Comment: @Karolis oh, you are quite right about that, my filename was called 'user', so I assumed. oops!